# Redundant tag world-war-2

Tags: bug, status-completed

[world-war-2](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-2) should be merged into [ww2](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ww2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I performed the merge while indicating they were synonyms. I think that was the appropriate response. Thanks for raising this.

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of whether they get merged, [ww2](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ww2) and [world-war-2](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-2) should be marked synonyms in the same way that [wwii](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wwii) already is. In fact, we could do with a good cleanup of tag synonyms:

1. [cultural-history](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cultural-history) should be a synonym of [culture](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture)
2. [political-history](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-history) should be a synonym of [politics](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics)
3. [social-history](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-history) should be a synonym of [society](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society)

And many more. If you are able, please check out the [tag-synonyms](https://history.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) page and vote on proposed synonyms. Although honestly the limitations are kind of a pointless pain.

(My preference is for the shorter tags to be the main one due to the precedent of  [economy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy) being the main tag for [economic-history](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economic-history). Plus naming tags *topic-history* seems quite redundant when the site is explicitly about history. But this is quite a minor point.)

Comment: Why not just merge the "*-history" tags (and thus get rid of them)? They all start similarly enough that the tag autocomplete should fill in the right tag name after the first few characters.

Comment: Merging is not mutually exclusive with setting up synonyms. By setting up synonyms, we can ensure future questions stay consolidated. Autocomplete is not a solution since they didn't stop these redundant tags forming, and it is in fact quite easy to type faster than autocomplete can make suggestions. I guess I just don't understand why you are so opposed. What possible downside could there possibly be?

Comment: I'm not sure that your examples are necessarily synonyms. Isn't it possible we could have cultural-history questions that are about the practice of cultural history and not solely about a culture?

Comment: @ihtkwot Certainly, but as was the [case for economics](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/1978/what-distinction-are-we-making-in-the-economics-and-economy-tags/), nobody seem to be using it like that. To be honest, given the volume of questions, I would think questions on the study of cultural history should just be tagged with historiography.

Answer (score 2):

Looking them over, it looks pretty clear that [ww2](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ww2) is the main tag. It has an actual tag description, way more entries (350ish compared to 17), and there's a [ww1](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ww1) tag to go with it.

However, there are a decent amount of questions under [world-war-2](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-2). So should it be a synonym, or just merged?

At the moment I'm feeling partial to making it a synonym (or rather doing *both*), as it would help taggers with searching.

Comment: Is there a difference?

Comment: @Lohoris - Yes. I found a decent discussion of it [on the math meta stack](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11163)

Comment: Definitely merging, then. They are just the same exact thing, just phrased differently.